# Facing the Security issue while trying to connect with IBM MQ through c# application (Reason code:2063 and 2035 )

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-mq

I have installed IBM MQ 9.2 version and trying to connect with c# application but facing the security issue[MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED-2035].

I have used these properties to connect through c# application.

```
string QueueManagerName = "***";
string QueueName = "***";
string ChannelInfo= "***/TCP/localhost(PORT)";

char[] separator = { '/' };

string[] ChannelParams; ChannelParams = ChannelInfo.Split(separator);
channelName = ChannelParams[0];

transportType = ChannelParams[1];

connectionName = ChannelParams[2];

MQQueueManager queueManager = new MQQueueManager(QueueManagerName,channelName, connectionName);
```

I found the following error message in MQ_DATA_PATH\qmgrs\qm-name\errors\AMQERR01.LOG

```
AMQ8079W: Access was denied when attempting to retrieve group membership information
for user ''

ACTION: Ensure Active Directory access permissions allow user '' to read
group memberships for user ''. To retrieve group membership
information for a domain user, MQ must run with the authority of a domain user
and a domain controller must be available.
```

Any help to resolve this issue will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please look in the queue manager AMQERR01.LOG file and post the error message(s) you see describing the problem to your question.

Comment: There is some general information on debugging 2035 in the [IBM Developer learn-mq sheet sheet](https://developer.ibm.com/components/ibm-mq/articles/mq-dev-cheat-sheet/). A default developer configuration is [documented in this tutorial](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/mq-connect-app-queue-manager-ubuntu/) and might help with validating your config.

Comment: @Morag Hughson , Thanks for your reply! I see that "AMQERR01.LOG" shows empty

Comment: Are you sure you looked at the queue manager AMQERR01.LOG - that is the one in MQ_DATA_PATH\qmgrs\<qm-name>\errors\AMQERR01.LOG. It would be highly unlikely to be empty.

Comment: @Morag Hughson You were right. i have checked in different path (MQ_DATA_PATH\errors). and I have looked into the above path and observed the below message  AMQ8079W: Access was denied when attempting to retrieve group membership information for user ACTION: Ensure Active Directory access permissions allow user '***' to read group memberships for user '***'. To retrieve group membership information for a domain user, MQ must run with the authority of a domain user and a domain controller must be available.

Comment: That error sounds like the answer to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not using a SYSTEM channel.

Create your own SVRCONN channel.  i.e. RK.TEST.CHL Then create a CHLAUTH rule to allow you to connect.  See examples here: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/example-using-back-stop-rule-together-mq-channel-authentication-rule-maps-client-user-fred-queue-manager-user-fulano

Next, issue setmqaut commands to allow your UserId to connect and access a queue:

```
setmqaut -m {QM_NAME} -t qmgr -g {GROUP} +connect +inq +dsp
setmqaut -m {QM_NAME} -n MY.QUEUE.** -t queue -g {GROUP} +allmqi +dsp
```

Comment: Hi Roger, thanks for your advice! I have used **.SVNCONN channel. I observe that channel always shows in an inactive state even after starting it.and i have given CHLAUTH rule as well. but issue still exists.

Answer (score 0):

Full example (presumes installation is complete)

1. Create Queue Manager named 'QMDEV1' as 'mqm' user

```
. /opt/mqm/bin/setmqenv -n Installation1
/opt/mqm/bin/crtmqm -lc -lf 65535 -lp 3 -ls 2 -u SYSTEM.DEAD.LETTER.QUEUE QMDEV1
/opt/mqm/bin/strmqm QMDEV1
```

2. Add MQ Objects -- including queue 'ORDER.INPUT'

```
. /opt/mqm/bin/setmqenv -n Installation1
/opt/mqm/bin/runmqsc QMDEV1 << EOF

ALTER QMGR MAXMSGL(4194304)
ALTER QL(SYSTEM.CLUSTER.TRANSMIT.QUEUE) MAXMSGL(4194304)
DEFINE LISTENER(QMDEV1.LISTENER) TRPTYPE(TCP) CONTROL(QMGR) PORT(1414)
START LISTENER(QMDEV1.LISTENER)
DEFINE CHANNEL(QMDEV1.SVRCONN) CHLTYPE(SVRCONN) MCAUSER('mqm') MAXMSGL(4194304) DESCR('Channel for incoming clients')
DEFINE QL(ORDER.INPUT)

end
EOF
```

3. Add a UNIX user account (as root)

```
groupadd ordergroup
useradd -G ordergroup order
```

4. Add MQ permissions for the 'ordergroup' to work with all queues prefix by 'ORDER.'

```
/opt/mqm/bin/setmqaut -m QMDEV1 -t qmgr -g ordergroup +connect +inq +dsp
/opt/mqm/bin/setmqaut -m QMDEV1 -n ORDER.** -t queue -g ordergroup +allmqi +dsp
```

5. Add CHLAUTH for 'order' user

```
. /opt/mqm/bin/setmqenv -n Installation1
/opt/mqm/bin/runmqsc QMDEV1 << EOF

SET CHLAUTH(QMDEV1.SVRCONN) TYPE(ADDRESSMAP) ADDRESS('*') USERSRC(NOACCESS)
SET CHLAUTH(QMDEV1.SVRCONN) TYPE(USERMAP) CLNTUSER('order') USERSRC(MAP) MCAUSER('order') ADDRESS('*') ACTION(ADD)

EOF
```

6. Validate CHLAUTH

```
. /opt/mqm/bin/setmqenv -n Installation1
/opt/mqm/bin/runmqsc QMDEV1 << EOF

DISPLAY CHLAUTH(QMDEV1.SVRCONN) MATCH(RUNCHECK) CLNTUSER('order') ADDRESS('1.2.3.4')

EOF
```

7. Send test message (Java JMS code sample)

```
MQConnectionFactory mqConnectionFactory = new MQConnectionFactory();
mqConnectionFactory.setHostName("qmdev1.mycompany.com");
mqConnectionFactory.setPort(1414);
mqConnectionFactory.setQueueManager("QMDEV1");
mqConnectionFactory.setChannel("QMDEV1.SVRCONN");
mqConnectionFactory.setTransportType(1);
        
Connection connection = mqConnectionFactory.createConnection("order", "order00");
Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
MessageProducer messageProducer = session.createProducer(session.createQueue("ORDER.INPUT"));
messageProducer.send(session.createTextMessage("Hello world!"));        
connection.start();
        
MessageConsumer messageConsumer = session.createConsumer(session.createQueue("ORDER.INPUT"));
Message message = messageConsumer.receive(2000l);
System.out.println("Received message body: " + TextMessage.class.cast(message).getText());
messageConsumer.close();
messageProducer.close();
session.close();
connection.close();
```

8. Verify by changing the username in the code in step #7 and you'll get an exception with reason code 2035.

Comment: A much better answer.  :)  Can you remove 'mqm' from the MCAUSER attribute of the DEFINE CHANNEL command?

Comment: @Matt Pavlovich , Thanks for your answer, it was a clear one. I have followed the steps exactly and created the user in Windows and used the same. I have used the above properties in an .net application but I still face the same issue Reason code:2035.(Note:I have used the hostname of my pc where MQ server is installed ,and iam running application in the same pc )